# Repainting GUI with new Elements parsed from XML when a JList item is chosen

Tags: java, xml, swing

I'm trying to make a choose your own adventure story using java and XML so far I have the XML parsing and the java displaying a GUI with a JTextPane displaying the scene descriptions and a JList displaying the options. The user chooses their desired option by selecting it in the list and pressing a JButton labeled "Confirm" but I don't know where to go from here I need a way to repaint the entire JFrame with new values taken from the XML when the user presses the button. Is there an easy way to do this I would like to avoid slapping a gigantic loop around everything or repeating my entire program with the new values here's my java code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;

import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import org.jdom.*;
import org.jdom.input.SAXBuilder;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollBar;

public class TextAdventureGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    /**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=-20,79
     */
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private static JList list;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private final JTextPane txtpn = new JTextPane();
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    private final JButton Button = new JButton("Confirm");

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {

                    File inputFile = new File("input");
                    SAXBuilder saxB = new SAXBuilder();

                    Document doc = saxB.build(inputFile);

                    Element storyElement = doc.getRootElement();

                    List<Element> scenesList = storyElement.getChildren();

                    Element sceneElement = scenesList.get(1);
                    List<Element> sceneChildren = sceneElement.getChildren();

                    List<Element> choicesList = sceneChildren.subList(1, sceneChildren.size());


                    TextAdventureGUI frame = new TextAdventureGUI(sceneElement, choicesList);
                    frame.setVisible(true);



                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public TextAdventureGUI(Element scene, List<Element> choices) {


        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 482, 311);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0));
        //String[] array = null; 
        list = new JList(choices.toArray());
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane_1);
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(txtpn);
        txtpn.setEditable(false);
        txtpn.setText(scene.getChildText("SceneDescription"));

        Button.addActionListener(this);

        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(list);

        contentPane.add(Button);

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(e.getActionCommand().equals("Confirm"));
        {
            Element Selection = (Element) list.getSelectedValue();
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the XML it parses:

```
<?xml version = "1.0"?>
<Story>
    <Scene id = "scene1">
        <SceneDescription>Insert Scene Description
        </SceneDescription>

        <choice no="1">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 1 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>end1</outcome>
        </choice>

        <choice no="2">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 2 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene3</outcome>
        </choice>
    </Scene>

    <Scene id = "scene2">
        <SceneDescription>You are in a room, it's dark but you can see a faint sliver of light coming from what looks like a crack in the door what would you like to do?
        </SceneDescription>

        <choice no="1">
            <choiceDescription>Wait Here </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene1</outcome>
        </choice>

        <choice no="2">
            <choiceDescription>Try to leave the room </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene3</outcome>
        </choice>

        <choice no="3">
            <choiceDescription>Open the door to let in light and search the room</choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene4</outcome>
        </choice>
    </Scene>

    <Scene id = "scene3">
        <SceneDescription>Insert Scene Description
        </SceneDescription>

        <choice no="1">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 1 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>end1</outcome>
        </choice>

        <choice no="2">
            <choiceDescription>choice description 2 </choiceDescription>
            <outcome>scene1</outcome>
        </choice>
    </Scene>

    <Scene id = "end1">
        <SceneDescription>ending
        </SceneDescription>

    </Scene>

</Story>
```

Basically I need to change the value of `Element sceneElement` to the `<outcome>` of whatever choice they confirm and I haven't the slightest idea how to do that can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I think you should try build the panels based on the scenes in your xml. And these panel should be arranged as a deck of cards placed on CardLayout. Based on the choice you can decide which card to show on the screen.

Comment: Use a [`ListSelectionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html) to see what list item was selected; in the listener's handler, update adjacent components to display elements of the corresponding scenario.

Comment: How do I change it to CardLayout and keep my current GridLayout on the cards?

Comment: Each card can have it's own layout,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are almost there.

1. You do not have re-intialise your list everytime.
2. Once you parse the model you have to create a scene(Model) based on the xml
3. Each scene will have list of choices(list of scene objects)
4. On confirming the list selection Pass the scene pertaining to the choice to load.

Hope the below code helps you.

The Scene Model

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;

/**
 *
 * @author user
 */
public class Scene {
   private  String id;
   private String descrition;

    List<Choice> choices = new ArrayList<Choice>();

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 3;
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Scene other = (Scene) obj;
        if (!Objects.equals(this.id, other.id)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Scene(String id, String descrition) {
        this.id = id;
        this.descrition = descrition;
    }

    public List<Choice> getChoices() {
        return choices;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescrition() {
        return descrition;
    }


}
```

The Choice Model

```
public class Choice {
    String id;
    String description;
    String outSceneId;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getOutSceneId() {
        return outSceneId;
    }

    public void setOutSceneId(String outSceneId) {
        this.outSceneId = outSceneId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Choice{" + "description=" + description + '}';
    }

}
```

And the Frame which displays the scenes

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import org.jdom2.*;
import org.jdom2.input.SAXBuilder;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class TextAdventureGUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    /**
     * @wbp.nonvisual location=-20,79
     */
    private final JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    private static JList list;
    JScrollPane scrollPane;
    private final JTextPane txtpn = new JTextPane();
    private final JScrollPane scrollPane_1 = new JScrollPane();
    private final JButton Button = new JButton("Confirm");
    private final DefaultListModel<Choice> model = new DefaultListModel<Choice>();

    private Map<String, Scene> scenesMap = new HashMap<String, Scene>();

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TextAdventureGUI storyBoard = new TextAdventureGUI();
                    File inputFile = new File("input");
                    SAXBuilder saxB = new SAXBuilder();

                    Document doc = saxB.build(inputFile);

                    Element storyElement = doc.getRootElement();
                    Scene firstScene = null;
                    List<Element> scenesList = storyElement.getChildren();
                    for (Element sceneElement : scenesList) {
                        Scene scene = storyBoard.buildScene(sceneElement);
                        storyBoard.getScenesMap().put(scene.getId(), scene);
                        if (firstScene == null) {
                            firstScene = scene;
                        }
                    }
                    storyBoard.initScene(firstScene);
                    storyBoard.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private Scene buildScene(Element sceneElement) {
        Scene scene = null;
        String id = sceneElement.getAttributeValue("id");
        if (id != null) {
            String sceneDescription = sceneElement.getChild("SceneDescription").getText();
            scene = new Scene(id, sceneDescription);
            for (Element element : sceneElement.getChildren()) {
                if (element.getName().equals("choice")) {
                    scene.getChoices().add(this.buildChoice(element));
                }
            }
        }
        return scene;
    }

    private Choice buildChoice(Element choiceElement) {
        Choice choice = null;
        String id = choiceElement.getAttributeValue("no");
        if (null != id) {
            choice = new Choice();
            choice.setId(id);
            choice.setDescription(choiceElement.getChildText("choiceDescription"));
            choice.setOutSceneId(choiceElement.getChildText("outcome"));
        }
        return choice;
    }

    public TextAdventureGUI() {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 482, 311);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 0));
        //String[] array = null; 
        list = new JList();
        list.setModel(model);
        scrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane_1);
        scrollPane_1.setViewportView(txtpn);
        txtpn.setEditable(false);
        Button.addActionListener(this);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);
        scrollPane.setViewportView(list);
        contentPane.add(Button);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getActionCommand().equals("Confirm"));
        {
            Choice choice = (Choice) list.getSelectedValue();
            Scene outCome = scenesMap.get(choice.getOutSceneId());
            if (outCome != null) {
                initScene(outCome);
            }
        }
    }

    public Map<String, Scene> getScenesMap() {
        return scenesMap;
    }

    public void initScene(Scene scene) {
        txtpn.setText(scene.getDescrition());
        model.clear();
        for (Choice choice : scene.getChoices()) {
            model.addElement(choice);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm going to need more help with the code on this I just went and manually added another frame using the cardlayout to see if I could properly replicate my gridlayout and it worked but I can't see a way to scale that to an XML file of unknown length.

Comment: @Bention It's throwing a type mismatch error on this line: `for (Element element : sceneElement.getChildren())` which I don't understand they should both be `Element` I can't see why it thinks on isn't

Comment: don't worry I fixed it it was just a list that needed to be more specifically declared